# get value in table contain list image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

anyone help me get value of rows with list image ?
I have a table with a description and list images, when I click SEND button I want to sent to server list images and description.
ex:
des: abc -> images.png, untitle.jpg
des: bcd -> download.png.

this my code:

```
$.each($("#tab_logic >tbody >tr.detailServices"), function (index, value) {

        var requestId = $(this).find(".requestId").val();
        var requestServiceId = $(this).find(".requestServiceId").val();
        var des = $(this).find(".description").val();
        var file;
        debugger
        if (requestId != undefined && des != undefined && requestServiceId != undefined) {
            formData.append("requestId", requestId);
            formData.append("des", des);
            formData.append("requestServiceId", requestServiceId);
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("fileUpload" + index).files;
            if (totalFiles.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles.length; i++) {
                        file = document.getElementById("fileUpload" + index).files[i];
                        formData.append("fileUpload" + index, file);
                    }
                }
            }
            var formData = {
                des: des,
                requestId: requestId,
                requestServiceId: requestServiceId,
                file: file
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ServiceRequest/AddScreenShot?plugin=ServiceRequestPlugin",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,         // PREVENT AUTOMATIC DATA PROCESSING.
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success !!!!!!")
                }
            });

        }

    });
```

[images about my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCiDW.png)